Determining number of observations be within confidence threshold
I have a model which has an accuracy of $A$. It makes a prediction with $Y$ confidence about a number of samples. Samples are observed many times, but not all are observed equally. So my data looks like:
Model Accuracy (A)    Model Prediction Confidence (Y)        Sample ID
0.80                              0.90                            1
0.80                              0.95                            1
0.80                              0.70                            1
0.80                              0.88                            2
0.80                              0.92                            2
0.80                              0.80                            3
0.80                              0.93                            4
0.80                              0.85                            4
0.80                              0.60                            4
0.80                              0.97                            4

I'd like to restrict my analysis to samples that I'm 95% sure are real. How many times must I have observed a sample for it to fall within this range, if I filter the model prediction to be strictly above a determined $X$.
My thinking here is that if I lower $X$ I'll have more samples in my data so despite being less confident in them perhaps that is outweighed by the confidence I get of having a greater number?
It's not possible for me to bootstrap the model.
Thank you for your help.

I was thinking perhaps the thing to do is for a threshold $X$ to calculate the ratio of log odds to get the required number of observations $N$:
$\lceil \frac{\ln(0.95 / (1 - 0.95))}{\ln(X / (1 - X))} \rceil$
And somehow incorporate the probability $A$

I could just do $X*A$ in my log odds.
